# trigger animation at the end of debounced requestanimationframe

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I followed Paul Lewis's guide to debounce and [requestAnimationFrame](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/animations/#requestanimationframe-and-high-resolution-timestamps). I'm translating an image across the screen on scroll when it comes into view.

```
var bicycles = $('.tandem-bike', context),
      lastScrollY = 0,
      ticking     = false;

  function update() {
    var windowHeight  = window.innerHeight,
        windowWidth   = $(window).width(),
        bikeTop       =  [];

    bicycles.each( function (i, el) {
      bikeTop[i]            = $(this).offset();
    });

    bicycles.each(function(i, el) {

      var position = bikeTop[i];
      var fromTop = position.top - windowHeight;
      var imgHeight = $(this).height();
      // When this image scrolls into view.
      if (lastScrollY > fromTop  && lastScrollY < position.top + imgHeight && i == 1 ) { // 375 ~= height of image

        var translate = Math.floor((lastScrollY - fromTop) / ((windowHeight + imgHeight + 300) / windowWidth));
        console.log('add tp tranlate ', translate);
        $(this).css('transform', 'translateX(' + (translate - 275) + 'px)');
      }
    });

    ticking = false;
  }

  function onScroll() {
    lastScrollY = window.scrollY;
    requestTick();
  }

  function requestTick() {
    if(!ticking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
      ticking = true;
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll, false);
```

This works great and the bicycle-built-for-two slides effortlessly across the screen. However, I want the image to "bounce" when the user stops scrolling. I figure an easy way would be to add a class when the animation ends, and pull it off when the animation starts. The obvious place to do that is within the `if` block in `requestTick()`.

```
    if(!ticking) {
      $('.tandem-bike').removeClass('bounce');
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
      $('.tandem-bike').addClass('bounce');
      ticking = true;
    }
```

or

```
    if(!ticking) {
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
      $('.tandem-bike').addClass('bounce');
      ticking = true;
    } else {
      $('.tandem-bike').removeClass('bounce');
    }
  }
```

Neither works, and I don't love then because I'm whole-sale adding classes to all the animated images on the page. (I would live with that if it worked)

Comment: The `requestTick()` function is calling on the each `scroll` event as user scrolls a page. It could occur a several times per second. The raF just throttles the `update()` in 16ms time intervals.  Is it needed to add and remove the "bounce" class so often? There are no such event as "user starts scrolling" or "user ends scrolling'. You may implement some heruistic for that.

Comment: Yeah, I only need to add the bounce class at the end of the "user scrolls" event. By heruistic, I'm guessing you mean a method for capturing the scroll event end.